# How to delete data from IOS-XE?

Tags: cisco

I would like to completely initialize the ASR1002 to securely pass the device to third party.

To delete all configuration in regular IOS, I usually run "write erase" and delete unnecessary file from "flash" by "delete flash:FILENAME" because I sometimes found backup configuration stored under flash:.

Is there any special way to delete configuration on IOS-XE?
I deleted startup and running config by following the instruction written here.
[How to erase running-configuration in Cisco IOS-XE?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/37635/how-to-erase-running-configuration-in-cisco-ios-xe)

And checked under bootflash:.

Here is the latest output by "show file systems".

```
 Router#show file systems
File Systems:

       Size(b)       Free(b)      Type  Flags  Prefixes
             -             -    opaque     rw   system:
             -             -    opaque     rw   tmpsys:
*   7819087872    7215439872      disk     rw   bootflash:
    2872836096    2384969728      disk     rw   fpd:

       2097152       1585152      disk     rw   obfl:

             -             -    opaque     rw   null:

             -             -    opaque     ro   tar:

             -             -   network     rw   tftp:

      33554432      33553356     nvram     rw   nvram:

             -             -    opaque     wo   syslog:

             -             -   network     rw   rcp:

             -             -   network     rw   ftp:

             -             -   network     rw   http:

             -             -   network     rw   scp:

             -             -   network     rw   https:

             -             -    opaque     ro   cns:


Router#
```

Comment: Isn't the space used on bootflash occupied by the IOS image? Adding the output of `dir /all` may be useful.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I actually deleted all directories and files under bootflash: by following commands.

```
Router#delete /force /recursive lost+found
Router#delete /force /recursive .prst_sync
Router#delete /force /recursive tracelogs.923
Router#delete /force /recursive tracelogs
Router#delete /force /recursive .installer
Router#delete /force /recursive .rollback_timer
Router#dir /all
Directory of bootflash:/
242881  drwx        4096  May 10 2017 02:03:45 +00:00  .rollback_timer
    14  -rw-   205119800   Mar 1 2016 16:32:14 +00:00  asr1000rp1-ipbasek9.02.04.02.122-33.XND2.bin
7819087872 bytes total (7216553984 bytes free)
Router#
```

HOWEVER, after reboot, as shown below some directories are recreated.
I guess it is OS-XE's normal behavior..

```
Router>en
Router#pwd
bootflash:
Router#dir /all
Directory of bootflash:/
242881  drwx        4096  May 10 2017 02:03:45 +00:00  .rollback_timer
437185  drwx        4096  May 10 2017 02:08:09 +00:00  tracelogs
    11  -rwx        5947  May 10 2017 02:04:30 +00:00  tracelogs.585
728641  drwx        4096  May 10 2017 02:06:18 +00:00  core
259073  drwx        4096  May 10 2017 02:06:18 +00:00  .prst_sync
129537  drwx        4096  May 10 2017 02:07:11 +00:00  .installer
    14  -rw-   205119800   Mar 1 2016 16:32:14 +00:00  asr1000rp1-ipbasek9.02.04.02.122-33.XND2.bin
7819087872 bytes total (7216197632 bytes free)
Router#
```

Comment: When you paste in configurations, use the Preformatted text option (`{}`). If your answer satifies your question, then you should accept it so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Ron. I will do so next time. I actually gave up to pass the device to the third party... As all configuration is deleted, I believe that the way I did should be OK, though...